# are there any alternative for cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

When i try to add `cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr` plugin in ionic 4, it shows the plugin which is unsupported. are there any alternatives for that?

i also tried with `Tesserect` it worked in browser but not supported to the mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of the plugin and since it is a purely cordova plugin, technincally it should work with no issues as long it was added correctly.

But a [similar issue](https://github.com/NeutrinosPlatform/cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr/issues/16) was raised in the github repo of the plugin and the solution is present there as well.

Adding the same solution here for anyone else who comes across this question.

> **Solution:**
>
> There is mistake in the
>   documentation.
>
> Instead of : import { MobileOCR } from '@ionic-native/ocr/ngx';
>
> Use this : import { OCR } from '@ionic-native/ocr/ngx';